# Auth module with deferred User module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have an `AuthModule` in a generalized library which requires interacting with a `UserModule` similar to the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication).

What I want to do is define an Interface that the `UserService` must adhere to instead of an actual implementation. This will leave the implementation details to the users of the library.

I've tried a few different approaches such as having a string token `APP_USER_SERVICE` initially `null` then be overridden by the implementor, but this seemed to run into trouble injecting a `null` value and not injecting the actual value.

Another approach I tried which I kind of like is doing `AuthModule.withUserModule(UserModule)` where `AuthModule` imports the dynamic `UserModule` and looks for the `APP_USER_SERVICE` token defined by the `UserModule` implementation. The problem with this approach is it seems to run into circular dependency hell.

I'm new to the NestJS project, so maybe I'm missing something obvious. Any pointers on how to organize this workflow is greatly appreciated, thanks.

In summary this is the structure I am going for:

-> = depends on

LIBRARY:

`AuthModule` -> `IUserModule`

USER:

`AuthModule.withUserModule(UserModule)` to fill in the `IUserModule` requirement.

`UserModule` -> `AuthModule`

Here is the code (broken atm):

[Library](https://github.com/BellwoodStudios/canary)
[Sample Implementation](https://github.com/BellwoodStudios/canary-base)

Comment: Working with `forwardRef()` should only be your last option. Can you not split the AuthModule in two parts, e.g. `AuthLoginModule` gets imported by the `UserModule` and `ValidateAuthModule` imports the `UserModule`?

Comment: I ended up splitting out the login logic from the UserModule which is similar to what you suggested. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with `forwardRef()` should only be your last resort. Alternatively, consider splitting one of the modules into two or more parts to break the circular dependencies, e.g.:

`AuthModule` into

- `AuthLoginModule` gets imported by the UserModule
- `ValidateAuthModule` imports the UserModule

or respectively the `UserModule` into two parts.