# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the BlahService although it is Global()

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have an issue with NestJS and it appears to be for just 1 module and all the others work fine. I have the following modules.

The error is:

```
[ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ApplicationService (ApplicationModel, AwsService, UserService, ?, JobService). Please make sure that the argument at index [3] is available in the ApplicationModule context.
```

The `AgencyService` is `[3]`. If I remove the `AgencyModule` from the `ApplicationModule` NestJS successfully compiles and I can make API calls.

```
AgencyModule,
ApplicationModule,
AuthModule,
JobModule,
UserModule,
```

All these modules are required by other modules for their service providers so rather than import them between each other using `forwardRef()` I just made them `Global()` - May not be best practice but hey ho (it works).

My `AppModule` file.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.get('MONGO_DB_URL'),
        useNewUrlParser: true,
      }),
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    ConfigModule,
    AgencyModule,
    ApplicationModule,
    AuthModule,
    DevModule,
    JobModule,
    UserModule,
    VideoModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Each module folder has the following structure.

```
agency/
- dto/
- agency.controller.ts
- agency.interface.ts
- agency.schema.ts
- agency.service.ts
- agency.module.ts
```

My `AgencyModule` file.

```
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Agency', schema: AgencySchema }]),
  ],
  controllers: [
    AgencyController,
  ],
  providers: [
    AgencyService,
    AwsService,
  ],
  exports: [
    AgencyService,
  ],
})
export class AgencyModule implements NestModule {
  public configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply()
      .forRoutes(
        { path: 'agency', method: RequestMethod.GET },
      );
  }
}
```

My `AgencyService` file.

```
@Injectable()
export class AgencyService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('Agency') private readonly agencyModel: Model<Agency>,
    private readonly awsService: AwsService,
    private readonly applicationService: ApplicationService,
  ) {
    //
  }

  // More stuff here but not worth adding to the snippet.

}
```

My `ApplicationModule` file.

```
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Application', schema: ApplicationSchema }]),
  ],
  controllers: [
    ApplicationController,
  ],
  providers: [
    ApplicationService,
    AwsService,
  ],
  exports: [
    ApplicationService,
  ],
})
export class ApplicationModule implements NestModule {
  public configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply()
      .forRoutes(
        { path: 'application', method: RequestMethod.GET },
      );
  }
}
```

My `ApplicationService` file.

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('Application') private readonly applicationModel: Model<Application>,
    private readonly awsService: AwsService,
    private readonly userService: UserService,
    private readonly agencyService: AgencyService,
    private readonly jobService: JobService,
  ) {
    //
  }

  // More stuff here but not worth adding to the snippet.

}
```

The `AwsService` is a shared service without a module.

Comment: Can you add the constructor of your `ApplicationService`?

Comment: I'll add a snippet to the original post.

Comment: Does the `AgencyService` use the `ApplicationService`?

Comment: Yes they are dependencies of each other.

Comment: I added my agency service file too.

Comment: Does it work when you remove the `ApplicationService` as a dependency? If yes, can you try using `@Inject(forwardRef(() => ...Service))` on both sides, see https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency

Comment: That seemed to work! Not sure why I have to do that if the module is global though... Can you make a proper answer and I will upvote it in case anyone else has the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `@Global()` does not automatically resolve circular dependencies, you still have to use `@Inject(forwardRef(() => MyService))` on both sides, see the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency).

---

As you noted yourself, circular dependencies (`forwardRef`) and global modules (`@Global`) are bad style and should be avoided. Rather make your dependencies explicit. If you encounter a circular dependency extract the commonly used parts in a shared service/module that is imported by both sides, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54640232/4694994).